# Deep Learning on Encrypted Images

Tags: hash, deep-learning

Suppose we have a set of images and labels meant for a machine-learning classification task. The problem is that these images come with a relatively short retention policy. While one could train a model online (i.e. update it with new image data every day), I'm **ideally interested in a solution that can somehow retain images for training and testing.**

To this end, I'm interested if there are any known techniques, for example some kind of one-way hashing on images, which obfuscates the image, but still allows for deep learning techniques on it.

I'm not an expert on this but the way I'm thinking about it is as follows: we have a `NxN` image `I` (say `1024x1024`) with pixel values in `P:={0,1,...,255}^3`, and a one-way hash map `f(I):P^(NxN) -> S`. Then, when we train a convolutional neural network on `I`, we first map the convolutional filters via `f`, to then train on a high-dimensional space S. I think there's no need for `f` to locally-sensitive, in that pixels near each other don't need to map to values in S near each other, as long as we know how to map the convolutional filters to S. Please note that it's imperative that `f` is not invertible, and that the resulting stored image in `S` is unrecognizable.

One option for `f,S` is to use a convolutional neural network on `I` to then extract the representation of `I` from it's fully connected layer. This is not ideal because there's a high chance that this network won't retain the finer features needed for the classification task. So I think this rules out a CNN or auto encoder for `f`.